# OrmLite clean query result after release OpenHelperManager

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I have 3 tables.

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "summary")
public class Summary {


@DatabaseField(columnName = _ID, generatedId = true)
private int id;

@DatabaseField (columnName = OPERATION_NAME)
private String operation;

@ForeignCollectionField(columnName = ENTRIES, eager = true)
private Collection<Entry> entries;
}
```

Second:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "entry")
public class Entry implements Parcelable {

@DatabaseField(columnName = _ID, generatedId = true)
private int _id;

@DatabaseField (foreign = true, columnName = SUMMARY, foreignAutoCreate = true)
private Summary summary;

@ForeignCollectionField(columnName = PARAMS, eager = true)
private Collection<Params> params;
}
```

Third:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "params")
public class Params implements Parcelable {

@DatabaseField(columnName = _ID, generatedId = true)
private int _id;


@DatabaseField (foreign = true, columnName = ENTRY, foreignAutoCreate = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
private Entry entry;
}
```

I made the query

```
List<Summary> summaries = new ArrayList<Summary>();
summaries = dao.queryForAll();
```

Each element of **summaries** contains Collection entries. Each element of entries contains Collection params;

I got the **List summaries** with records, but after 
     OpenHelperManager.releaseHelper();
I lose data of Collection  which contains data from third table from summaries. I get IllegalStateException.
Why?

Comment: You've nicely set-up the problem, but you've only given the code that works.  You will get a better quality of responses if you edit the question to add the part of the code that exhibits the error you're seeing, ideally using comments or some other indication to describe what you're expecting to happen, and what you're actually seeing.  As someone familiar w/Java and Android, I can't quite figure out what you mean by "losing a Collection" from what you've shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem. I need to increase maxEagerLevel to 2(default 1).

Set this to be the number of times to expand an eager foreign collection's foreign collection. If you query for A and it has an eager foreign-collection of field B which has an eager foreign-collection of field C ..., then a lot of database operations are going to happen whenever you query for A. By default this value is 1 meaning that if you query for A, the collection of B will be eager fetched but each of the B objects will have a lazy collection instead of an eager collection of C. It should be increased only if you know what you are doing.

```
int maxEagerLevel()
```